# Problem in getting DST time?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, timezone

I am trying to get the time of other GMT value by using

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(gmt));
```

but how can i get the DST time at that time zone.

Answer (score 0):

There are few methods available in [java.util.TimeZone](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/java/util/TimeZone.html) to get Daylight Saving Time. Please check out the BlackBerry Java Docs page.

Answer (score 0):

The TimeZone class provides a getDSTSavings() method for a specific TimeZone Object. (JavaDoc: "Returns the amount of time to be added to local standard time to get local wall clock time.")

The Calendar interface provides two getOffset() methods, which let you find out the offset from UTC. (JavaDoc: "Returns the offset of this time zone from UTC at the specified date. If Daylight Saving Time is in effect at the specified date, the offset value is adjusted with the amount of daylight saving. ")

please see this piece of code to grok the complicated ways of java time:

```
@Test
public void testDST() {
    final TimeZone met = TimeZone.getTimeZone("MET");
    Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(met);
    final long timeInMillis = gc.getTimeInMillis();
    final long gmtTime= timeInMillis-(gc.getTimeZone().getOffset(timeInMillis));
    final Date gmtDate = new Date(gmtTime);
    System.out.printf("%-40s: %tc\n%-40s: %tc\n%-40s: %tc\n%-40s: %d\n%-40s: %d",
            "new Date() (local timezone)",new Date(), 
            "UTC", gmtDate , 
            "now from Calendar with TC GMT+02:00",gc,
            "zoneoffset",gc.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET), 
            "dst savings",met.getDSTSavings());

}
```

You can also define your own SimpleTimeZone and provide custom DST rules, however, i have not found out how to get this information from the predefined TimeZones.

You should also be aware, that if TimeZone.getTimeZone(TZName) does not find the specified timezone, it does not throw an exception, but it just uses GMT, which can cause major misunderstandings.

You can find all this information (and a lot more) in javadoc for Calendar, TimeZone, Date, etc.

Comment: It wasn't entirely clear in the question, but BlackBerry uses Java-Me, so doesn't have the full Java SE API available.   See http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/java/util/TimeZone.html

Comment: Ok, i wasnt aware that this should work on blackberry. However from the documentation link you posted, i see it has getOffset and getRawOffset. The difference between those should give you the current daylight saving amount.